# Uploading ARReferenceImage from Array to Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an app, where I have sets of `ARReferenceImages` in a database, for users to download and use. These `ARReferenceImages` are create by the user.

I have coded everything up to where the user has created `ARReferenceImages`, which are put into and array, but this is where I am completely stumped.

It seems quite easy to upload `UIImages` to storage, but when it comes to `ARReferenceImages` I simply cannot find anywhere that tells me what to do.

I have tried getting the path to the file on my phone, but this seemingly isn't enough, or correct. So I am wondering if I should upload the images as `UIImages` and save the width of each image separately, whereupon I convert them into `ARReferenceImages` on downloading to the phone. But it just seems silly, if I could upload and download the actual `ARReferenceImage` as is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The code sample I have added is just to show what I am trying to do. The uploadData let throws an error, as it should be of type `Data()` and not of type `URL`. But I just don't know how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

```
`
for referenceImage in referenceImagesArray {

    let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: referenceImage.name, 
    withExtension: nil)

    let thisGameStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(folderRef).child(referenceImage.name ?? "")

            // Get image data
            if let uploadData = urlPath {

                // Upload image to Firebase Cloud Storage
                thisGameStorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { 
(metadata, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around for hours and have read Firebase documentation, swift documentation as well as reading and viewing several tutorials and I have come up with the following conclusion.

It seems that what I am trying to do is very difficult, or maybe a bad idea, since even if it might work, it could break the app because ARReferenceImages might be too heavy for the way I am trying to do it. So the solution I am going to use, is that I will:

1. Take images with camera, while also adding the real world width of the images. These will be stored as UIImages and CGFloats with names that reference each other.
2. I will then save the UIImages and the CGFloats separately, with the UIImage in Firebase Cloud Storage and the CGFloat in the Firebase Real Time Database.
3. When I need to use them as an ARReferenceImage, I will retrieve both images and widths and convert them into ARReferenceImages that I can put into an array and use with my AR app.

It takes a few steps, but as I had to convert the image to ARReferenceImage anyway, I can move that piece of code from the uploading part to the downloading part of my app, so I won't get many more actual lines of code.

Most of this code is not difficult, but for the main question I'll add the code I wrote for saving the UIImages from my array:

```
`var counter = 0
 for uiImage in uiImagesArray {
     let imageName = "image\(uiImagesArray[counter])"
     saveImage(imageName: imageName, theImage: uiImage, storageRef: 
     imagesStorageRef)
     counter = counter + 1
 }`

`func saveImage(imageName: String, theImage: UIImage, storageRef: 
 StorageReference){
    //get the PNG data for image
    let imageData = theImage.pngData()
    //create reference for storage
    let thisStorageRef = storageRef.child(gameTitle + "/" + imageName)
    //upload it to Firebase
    thisStorageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil)
}`
```

If anyone wants to see more of my code, for the other parts of this, just comment and I'll post it.